# Not able to download Spring Roo

Tags: spring, download, spring-tool-suite, spring-roo

I tried downloading Spring Roo from their official website, but nothing happens once I click on the download button.
It loads for a few seconds and nothing happens. I am sure there isn't any network issue.
Can anyone tell how should I download it or any other way to fix my problem?

Comment: Seems to work fine for me. Which official website do you use?

Comment: https://projects.spring.io/spring-roo/#running-from-shell
I tried to download from here.

Comment: The [download link](http://spring-roo-repository.springsource.org.s3.amazonaws.com/release/ROO/spring-roo-2.0.0.RELEASE.zip) in that page works for me. Maybe you could you try another browser or a command line utility like _wget_ to download the file.

Comment: Please keep in mind that Spring Roo is not actively developed anymore, so I would not recommend this for starting new projects. Spring Boot is the way to go... :-)

Comment: the purpose is very different, the commands roo supports like, for example : you have your domain designed and now you need to generate the repositories, roo can do this in one go https://docs.spring.io/spring-roo/docs/current/reference/html/#spring-data-repositories